# JSON iphone help desperately needed

Tags: iphone, xml, json

Hi desperate newbie in need of direction!  Well I say newbie, I have almost built myself the app I set out to achieve, a tableview to display story titles from my website, that when touched using the navigation controller slides to the story/article.

Only problem is that I only have test data that is embedded into my views as an array (which is no good to me).  I need this data to come from my website,  www.theknowledgeoflondon.com.  I want to take the title to display in the tableview and then when touch it slide to the actual article.

Been reading up and believe that JSON could be the answer or XML?  I do not have a clue on this subject and if I thought learning object c and coco touch was hard this JSON OR XML thing seems to be a new world of PAIN for me!!! and there doesn’t seem to be anything by way of good tutorials out there for someone that has not a clue on the subject.  My data is drawn from a simple MySql table from a php script and was hoping there is an easy way to feed this into my table view?

Would be very greatful for any information on a good way forward.  Have already downloaded SBJson, but then read that JSONTouch is a good alternative to use.  Or should I be using straight XML.  Any help and good tutorials would be much appriciated.

Thanks you in advance.
Steve

Comment: you don't have to limit yourself to JSON or XML. there are simpler formats ranging from plain text to CSV to YAML on up. just pick the simplest thing that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I made an app last week that uses XML and I found it the easier way of doing what you want to do. But I found an awesome tutorial that I believe is perfect for what you are trying to do. It helps you create the web service needed and teaches you how to access the data that you wish to access.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

and also check

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

And for even more information on web related subjects also have a look at www.w3schools.com it is an amazing website dedicated to teach about web technologies such as XML and the like.

Hope it helps you as much as it has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to choose then I will suggest to use plist format. Open a plist file with a plain text editor. You will find that that is actually a XML file. The big advantage of using plist is that you don't need another parser. You can convert a plist file directly to `NSArray` using `arrayWithContentsOfFile` or `arrayWithContentsOfURL` or convert them directly to `NSDictionary` by using similar methods. And you can create them using plist editor of Mac easily.